# Adding UITapGestureRecognizer to subview on tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

everyone, I am trying to add gesture recognizer to StackView which located on TableViewCell with that code and it doesn't work:

```
@IBOutlet var categoryStackView: UIStackView! {
    didSet {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(categoryStackViewTapped))
        categoryStackView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work, I checked StackView and it is enable for user interactive

```
@objc func categoryStackViewTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Here we are")
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that your code inside `didSet` in called?

Comment: can you edit your post to include your function `categoryStackViewTapped`? That would help to debug your issue. Also, did you put a print statement inside the function to check if its being called?

Comment: @FangmingNing yes, if I do this code like self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture) then it works for all cell

Comment: @TheoStrauss added

Comment: great. it looks like it would be called. is that print statement not printing? also, looking at your other comments, you said that it would "work for all cells." are you using a tableviewcontroller? if so, then if you do something to the one example cell, it will affect all other cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suggesting another approach if you have multiple `stackView` in your `tableView`. Add the current index row as tag to your , and then add click action to your button handler function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! Cell
    cell.stackView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.stackView.addTarget(self, action:#selector(categoryStackViewTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

Then in your handler function, you can get the correct index path by reading this tag

```
func categoryStackViewTapped(sender: UIStackView) {
    let myIndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    //... other code here
}
```